# How can I set the default Google Drive account used?

Tags: google-account, google-drive

I have two Google accounts set up on my phone, both are also present in Google Drive.

When I open the Gallery app and chose to *share* a picture via Google Drive, it will always be shared with the same account. Of course, I want it to use the **other** account.

I can not figure out how to do it. I would happily accept it if the *wrong* account was completely removed from Google Drive on my phone.

I tried disabling sync for the account I don't want in Google Drive, but that didn't have any effect on the problem. I don't want to completely remove the account from my phone, as I have purchased apps with that account and I fear that I won't be able to install/use them otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't realize you can change the account to use when uploading the file. I don't understand how I missed it, but here it is:

[image]

Given that the marked account value always changes back to the *other* account and I have to adjust it every time, I guess there is still merit in the question. But my problem was finding this UI item.